# Convergence of  $\lim_{n,v \rightarrow \infty}  \int_0^1 g'_n (x) e^{-i2\pi v x} \mbox{d} x $

Tags: fourier-analysis

$f(x, y) : (0,1)^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R $, is a continuous function, and its partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ are all integrable. if  $y=\mbox{mod}(n^2 x,1)$, i.e.,  $y$ is $\frac{1}{n^2}$-periodic over $x$, we can write 
$$ g_n(x) = f(x, \mbox{mod}(n^2 x,1))$$ 
and let $g_n'(x)$  be its derivative, as $n, v \in \mathbb N$  goes to infinity simultaneously with the ratio $n/v$ remain a constant, I'm looking for a proof of the convergence of
$$\lim_{n,v \rightarrow \infty}  \int_0^1 g_n'(x) e^{-i2\pi v x}\mbox{d} x $$

Comment: Could you please give a bit more background on where you've run into this question, what you need the answer for, and so on? The way your question is worded ("prove that...") makes it sound like an exercise that's been assigned, but if this isn't the case then giving more context may help people to give more useful answers

Comment: Yemon, this is a problem I encountered when tried to find out the convergence rate of the Fourier coefficients of $g_n(x)$ as $n$ and $v$ increase simultaneously.  

Comment: If this isn't homework, it should be...

Comment: The same question was posted a few days ago on math.SE, but it hasn't attracted much attention: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16902/convergence-of-lim-n-v-rightarrow-infty-int-01-g-n-x-e-i2-pi-v-x

Comment: and the solution follows immediately from this result: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15942/convergence-of-lim-n-v-rightarrow-infty-int-01-f-n-x-e-i2-pi-v-x

Comment: @Nick, No, $g_n(x)$ is not a periodic function as in that question.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more precise as to what you mean by "as $n, v$ goes to infinity simultaneously at the same rate"? (There has been quite a bit written about potential problems with convergence of Fourier series in two variables, where the way you sum the double series becomes important; this may or may not be relevant here.)

Comment: You haven't said anything about proper conditions. You didn't assume $f$ to be differentiable at the start, but you later talk about $g_n'$. As Yemon says, it's also very unclear what your limiting process is. I think your question is almost meaningless as stated, and needs to be far more precise.

Comment: ...also, you need to assume something about $g_n'$ or the partial derivatives of $f$, or similar (just saying "they exist" is not enough; if you're assuming the derivatives to be continuous, then say so!!) Without clearly stated assumptions on the allowable functions $f$ and the limiting process, this question cannot be sensibly answered.

Comment: Hi, Yemon, Zen and Nick, thank you all for helping me to clarify the question. I've made some effort to improve the question. 

Answer (score 1):

If we take $f(x,y)=2\sqrt x$, so that $g_n'(x)=1/\sqrt x$, then your integrals do not exist at all.

Comment: No, $(1-e^{-2\pi iv})=0$ as $v \in \mathbb N \/$. It is converged. 

Comment: Wadim, thanks for your remind. So I exclude 0 from the domain.

Comment: Maple recognizes the real and imaginary part of the proposed integral in terms of Fresnel C functions, and tells me that the limit exists as v tends to infinity. Knowing nothing about Fresnel C functions, I wouldn't bet on Maple's correctness.  I do agree with the others that this problem should be stated more precisely.